# nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:20

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

**Objective:**
I want to use a Windows server for local DNS

Running into an issue and I have seen and tried many different suggestions here and everywhere and the result is the same. I am sure it is something simple but cant put my finger on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried using a proxy_pass, upstream configuration and resolver and still the same error.

```
resolver 10.90.10.11 valid=10s;

server {
    location / {
        set $backend_servers example.com;
        proxy_pass http://$backend_servers;
    }
}
```

https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/

[nginx resolver -- dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641685/nginx-resolver-dns)

```
**Error**
nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:20
```

```
**Configuration:**
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

**Application**: Wordpress 6.2

Reverse-Proxy Config

```
`server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /var/www/html/wordpress;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/ssl-bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mykey.comkey.key;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    client_max_body_size 500M;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }`
```

Hosts File

```
cpadmin@3SWEB1:/etc$ cat hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       3SWEB1

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

10.90.10.11  example.com #Windows DNS server

**Netstat -plnt**

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Tried these three solutions:

1. [nginx resolver -- dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641685/nginx-resolver-dns)
2. https://www.nginx.com/blog/dns-service-discovery-nginx-plus/
3. https://dev.to/ivishalgandhi/local-home-lab-dns-setup-with-dnsmasq-and-nginx-8b5

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` (NOT in sites-enabled. You change the file in sites-available and that will reflected in sites-enabled).

The error is telling you that something is wrong in line 20 of the file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`. You have the same location twice and have to delete (or comment out) one of them.